# Spring Data Neo4j executes wrong query from repositories

Tags: neo4j, cypher, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j

As the title, `Spring Data Neo4j` doesn't execute the right derived queries. Let me clarify the concept with an example. I have the following class

```
@RelationshipEntity
public class MashupToMashupSimilarity {

    private float score;
    //GETTER AND SETTER
}
```

and to access the objects of the class I use a simple repository class

```
public interface MashupToMashupSimilarityRepository extends
    GraphRepository<MashupToMashupSimilarity> {

     public Set<MashupToMashupSimilarity> findByScoreGreaterThan(float score);
}
```

When I execute the method above, the logger shows the following query

```
DEBUG [CypherQueryEngine] - Executing cypher query: START `mashupToMashupSimilarity`=node:__types__(className="package.MashupToMashupSimilarity") WHERE `mashupToMashupSimilarity`.`score`! > {0} RETURN `mashupToMashupSimilarity` params {0=0.1}
```

Note that it use `node:__types__` as index, while instead it should use `rel:__rel_types__`; so, it always return an empty result set. OTH, if I execute the query replacing the wrong index with the right one, the it returns right results.

The strange thing is that invoking `MashupToMashupSimilarityRepository#findAll()` (or `#count()` or other inherited methods inherited from the above repositories) the result sets are non empty. However, I don't know which kind of query got executed because ATM I haven't found a way to log the queries.

Is this a bug or I am missing something? I use the following versions and I'm unable to upgrade them

```
<spring.version>3.1.2.RELEASE</spring.version>
<spring-data-neo4j.version>2.1.0.RELEASE</spring-data-neo4j.version>
<neo4j.version>1.9.M02</neo4j.version>
```

Comment: Thanks for reporting it, this is a bug, please raise an issue in the Spring Source JIRA https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAGRAPH