# Cypher 1.9.9, START by both relationship and node index

Tags: neo4j, cypher, spring-data-neo4j

My `Neo4j 1.9.9` entities are stored using `Spring Data Neo4j`. However, because many [derived queries from repository methods are wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31224826/spring-data-neo4j-executes-wrong-query-from-repositories), I've been forced to use directly `Cypher`

Basically, I have two classes:

```
@NodeEntity
public class RecommenderMashup {

    @Indexed(indexType = IndexType.SIMPLE, indexName = "recommenderMashupIds")
    private String mashupId;
}


@RelationshipEntity(type = "MASHUP_TO_MASHUP_SIMILARITY")
public class MashupToMashupSimilarity {

    @StartNode
    private RecommenderMashup mashupFrom;
    @EndNode
    private RecommenderMashup mashupTo;
}
```

In addition to the indexes directly provided, as you know, `Spring Data Neo4j` adds two other indexes: `__types__` for nodes and `__rel_types__` for relationship; both of them have `className` as their key.

So, I've tried the query below to get all the `MashupToMashupSimilarity` objects related to a specific node

```
START `mashupFrom`=node:`recommenderMashupIds`(`mashupId`='5367575248633856'),
`mashupTo`=node:__types__(className="package.RecommenderMashup"),
 `mashupToMashupSimilarity`=rel:__rel_types__(className="package.MashupToMashupSimilarity") 
MATCH `mashupFrom`-[:`mashupToMashupSimilarity`]->`mashupTo` 
RETURN `mashupToMashupSimilarity`;
```

However, I always got empty results. I suspect that this is due to the fact that the `START` clause contains both nodes and relationships. Is this possible? Otherwise, what could be the problem here?

### Additional infos

The suspect came from the fact that

```
START `mashupToMashupSimilarity`=rel:__rel_types__(className='package.MashupToMashupSimilarity') 
RETURN `mashupToMashupSimilarity`;
```

and

```
START `mashup`=node:__types__(className="package.RecommenderMashup") 
RETURN `mashup`;
```

and other similar queries always return the right results.
The only working alternative at this point is

```
START `mashupFrom`=node:`recommenderMashupIds`(`mashupId`='6006582764634112'),
`mashupTo`=node:__types__(className="package.RecommenderMashup") 
MATCH `mashupFrom`-[`similarity`:MASHUP_TO_MASHUP_SIMILARITY]->`mashupTo` 
RETURN `similarity`;
```

both I don't know how it works in terms of performance (the indexes should be faster). Also, I'm curious what I've been doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to run your queries in the neo4j-browser or shell? did they work there?

This query is also wrong,

```
START `mashupFrom`=node:`recommenderMashupIds`(`mashupId`='5367575248633856'),
`mashupTo`=node:__types__(className="package.RecommenderMashup"),
 `mashupToMashupSimilarity`=rel:__rel_types__(className="package.MashupToMashupSimilarity") 
MATCH `mashupFrom`-[:`mashupToMashupSimilarity`]->`mashupTo` 
RETURN `mashupToMashupSimilarity`;
```

you use `mashupToMashupSimilarity` as identifier for the relationship,

- but then you use it wrongly as relationship-type: 
  `-[:mashupToMashupSimilarity]->`
- it should be: `-[mashupToMashupSimilarity]->`
- but of course better, skip the rel-index check and use `-[similarity:MASHUP_TO_MASHUP_SIMILARITY]->`

And you can just leave of the relationship-index lookup which doesn't make sense at all, as you should already filter with the relationship-type.

#### Update: Don't use index lookups for type check

```
START mashupFrom=node:recommenderMashupIds(mashupId='5367575248633856')
MATCH (mashupFrom)-[mashupToMashupSimilarity:MASHUP_TO_MASHUP_SIMILARITY]->(mashupTo) 
WHERE mashupTo.__type__ = 'package.RecommenderMashup'
RETURN mashupToMashupSimilarity;
```

As the relationship-type is already restricting, I think you don't even need the type-check on the target node.

Comment: Hey Michael, yes indeed I uses all the available means and all kind of queries, but they all give wrong result. Regarding the `:`, I've tried to not use them, but as a result I get ALL the relationships of `__type__ =  'package.MashupToMashupSimilarity'`; i.e., the `mashupFrom` and `mashupTo` node are not considered at all. Is this the normal behaviour?
The other reason that made me use the identifier as relationship-type is that even `Spring Data Neo4j` use something similar (altough the derived query are wrongly put together) . So, is it the latter approach the suggested way?

Comment: I would not use the indexes for the type check at all. I updated my answer.